# Parsing a text file with multiple tags and writing it to another text file

Tags: java, xml, text-parsing

Need to read a text file which looks like an XML.The text file comprises of  multiple XML files  ,with a parent tags  .Need to parse the file and line by line and need to write the corresponding elements of the required  child tags even  repeated multiple times within  the parent tag , in a single line, to another text file .Need to write the elements to a next line after the parent tag.I know how to read a file and write the file ,But I am unable to get the logic to read it acording to the requirement .Please help me out .

```
    <parentnode xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:abcde="http://www.abcde.com/ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/ext /../xmls/XYZ/recordkeeping/abcde-ext.xsd">
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.google.com">1234566546</Child1>
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/UNique">AbcdeXYZ-23243423</Child1>
<country countryScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/country-identifier">1030253498</country>
<state stateScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/state-identifier">23423423423</state>
</parentnode>

<parentnode xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:abcde="http://www.abcde.com/ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/ext /../xmls/XYZ/recordkeeping/abcde-ext.xsd">
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.google.com">1234566546</Child1>
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/UNique">AbcdeXYZ-154555</Child1>
<country countryScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/country-identifier">1030253498</country>
<state stateScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/state-identifier">434343242</state>
</parentnode>

<parentnode xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:abcde="http://www.abcde.com/ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/ext /../xmls/XYZ/recordkeeping/abcde-ext.xsd">
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.google.com">1234566546</Child1>
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/UNique">AbcdeXYZ-4566545</Child1>
<country countryScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/country-identifier">1030253498</country>
<state stateScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/state-identifier">2323232323</state>
</parentnode>
```

Comment: lots of things you need to do here. better get started! show us some of your xml file or collection.

Comment: It would be better if you post a sample input file and then post the output that you are expecting. I am not able to understand anything from the OP.

Comment: StAX might help you to parse the the file, though I'm not sure how it behaves when you have several root elements in your file...

Comment: @hellboy A file has been attahed ,please help me

Comment: @Puce this is not a XML to pares it is text file comprising data of XML format.

Comment: @KlemensMorbe Any other details you want please let me know .

Comment: @Euphoria I'm aware of that, but if you're lucky StAX might still work. Or does it include non-XML data as well?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to do your file a valid xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootnode>
    <parentnode xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping"
        fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:abcde="http://www.abcde.com/ext"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/ext /../xmls/XYZ/recordkeeping/abcde-ext.xsd">
        <Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.google.com">1234566546</Child1>
        <Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/UNique">AbcdeXYZ-23243423</Child1>
        <country
            countryScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/country-identifier">1030253498</country>
        <state stateScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/state-identifier">23423423423</state>
    </parentnode>

    <parentnode xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping"
        fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:abcde="http://www.abcde.com/ext"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/ext /../xmls/XYZ/recordkeeping/abcde-ext.xsd">
        <Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.google.com">1234566546</Child1>
        <Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/UNique">AbcdeXYZ-154555</Child1>
        <country
            countryScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/country-identifier">1030253498</country>
        <state stateScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/state-identifier">434343242</state>
    </parentnode>

    <parentnode xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping"
        fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:abcde="http://www.abcde.com/ext"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/ext /../xmls/XYZ/recordkeeping/abcde-ext.xsd">
        <Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.google.com">1234566546</Child1>
        <Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/UNique">AbcdeXYZ-4566545</Child1>
        <country
            countryScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/country-identifier">1030253498</country>
        <state stateScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/state-identifier">2323232323</state>
    </parentnode>
</rootnode>
```

And then you can start reading your file, just check it out.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("file.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("parentnode");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                System.out.println("Current Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Child1").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Child1").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("country").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("state").item(0).getTextContent());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help , it was right which was said by you ib XML format,but I am asking about the input file in text format which comprises of many XML together in one text file , its supposed be a text file .

Comment: can you please tell me more about it? i see no reason why u should read an xml or a collection of xml like a normal text file. I know you want to read it line by line, but thats not how xml works.

Comment: I have a collection of XML in a text file it is a log file that is being generated .I need to find out a particular element how many times has particular element is repeated ..

Comment: thats it? you need to count the element tags and thats all? or do you have to count the attributes either?

Comment: Mobe : need to writhe the tag element to another text file , like required child tag values of in one line that belong to a parent tag

Comment: how should the output of the new file look like? did you solve it?

Comment: :I did not solve it ,and the output should look like  

Child1-value 
child1-value ....

in a text file